# Lack of Transaction ID on successful PayPal payment?

Tags: paypal

We are using PayPal's express check-out in order to handle payments in some scenarios.  Occasionally we run into situations when it appears that a successful payment has gone through, but there is no transaction id returned when PayPal POSTs the transaction details back to our site.  Has anyone else run into this situation?  It seems like it might be related to payments that are flagged as "Pending" but we have not been able to successfully recreate the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support for further assistance on this. 
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask